# What is the difference between LTree and LTree_Gist in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, ltree

In create table wizard of PGAdmin 4 when you open the column type drop-down menu, there is a type named `ltree_gist`.

Knowing that GIST is probably the best index option to use upon `ltree` columns, I suspect that `ltree_gist` is just `ltree` with an index defined on it as it is reasonable to create a `ltree` type column with a `GIST` index in just one move. But looks like its not that!

Long story short, could someone please explain the difference between `ltree` and `ltree_gist` in PGAdmin4 interface?

I could not find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ltree_gist` is an implementation detail that is used for the implementation of GiST index support for `ltree` values. It is used for storing index entries.

That type cannot be used in SQL or table definitions directly.

Comment: If it is for internal use, I wonder why is it in the drop down list then?!  Thanks for your answer

Comment: Because it is a data type, and pgAdmin just lists all data types.